# Possible to Parse this semi-structured text file using BeautifulSoup or regex in Python

Tags: python, regex, parsing, beautifulsoup

How can I parse this text file I have and extract only the first value in each line?

**file.txt**:

http://google.com,username2,mypassword1

http://yahoo.com,username3,mypassword2

http://ebay.com,username4,mypassword7

**expected output**:

```
http://google.com
http://yahoo.com
http://ebay.com
```

Is it possible to do in beautiful soup or some kind of regex?

Comment: Check out the [csv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to just split by `,`.

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line.split(',', 1)[0])
```

Providing the `maxsplit` argument to `str.split` is optional here, but a little more efficient since you only need to split once.

Answer (score 1):

BeautifulSoup is an HTML parser - since your file has no HTML, it wouldn't really do much of anything.

Here's a regex, though, that will find any domain with .com, and ignore the rest:

```
(.+\.com)
```

so, to implement it in Python..

```
tester = re.compile(r'(.+\.com)')
links = tester.match(linefromfile)
```